# Make: no remake on mac

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have some kind of make dependency problem. `all_2` does not rebuild after `a1.src` has been touched, but `all_1` does. Why? Can't I use absolute paths?

```
$ cat Makefile 
DIR = ${HOME}/tmp
outputs = $(DIR)/dir1/a1.out $(DIR)/dir2/a2.out

all_1 : dir1/a1.out dir2/a2.out

all_2 : $(outputs)
    ls -l $(outputs) # debug print

*/%.out : $(notdir %.src)
    @touch $@
    @echo 'Build $@ from $(notdir $*.src)'
```

This is my directory structure:

```
$ ls -R
Makefile    a1.src      a2.src      dir1        dir2

./dir1:
a1.out

./dir2:
a2.out
```

`all_1` works fine:

```
$ touch a1.src 
$ make all_1
Build dir1/a1.out from a1.src
$ make all_1
make: Nothing to be done for `all_1'.
```

but `all_2` does not rebuild `a1.out` (although the out files exist, so I guess that the targets are ok):

```
$ touch a1.src 
$ make all_2
ls -l /Users/eternity/tmp/dir1/a1.out /Users/eternity/tmp/dir2/a2.out # debug print
-rw-r--r--  1 eternity  staff  0 Jan 20 15:25 /Users/eternity/tmp/dir1/a1.out
-rw-r--r--  1 eternity  staff  0 Jan 20 14:46 /Users/eternity/tmp/dir2/a2.out
$
```

Comment: Makefiles are not shell scripts.  You can't use `*` in makefile targets (e.g., to make the `*` in `*/%.out:` is just a normal character, not a globbing character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `*` is not a "wildcard" in the target side. You need a *pattern rule* with `%.out` as target:

```
%.out: ...
```

That will match against target names with a trailing `.out`.

The *stem* (i.e.: the `%` part in the target) with which the pattern rule was matched against will be stored in the automatic variable `$*`:

```
%.out: $(notdir $*.src)
```

However, that alone won't do: **you also need to enable *secondary expansion*** to use the variable `$*` as part of the *rule definition*, because its value is empty during the first expansion. In order to enable secondary expansion, simply define the target `.SECONDEXPANSION`, i.e.:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
```

Once enabled, for delaying the expansion of a variable or function at the rule definition, you need to replace `$` by `$$`:

```
%.out: $$(notdir $$*.src)
```

So, with all that in mind, your last rule should look like:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.out: $$(notdir $$*.src)
    @touch $@
    @echo 'Build $@ from $(notdir $*.src)'
```